# seaborn heatmap can't show anotation

Tags: seaborn

I try to use `seaborn.heatmap` to show a matrix

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # generating 2-D 10x10 matrix of random numbers
    # from 1 to 100
    data = np.random.randint(low=1,
                             high=100,
                             size=(10, 10))

    # setting the parameter values
    annot = True

    # plotting the heatmap
    hm = sns.heatmap(data=data,
                     annot=annot)

    # displaying the plotted heatmap
    plt.show()
```

Run the code I got this, just the first line annotated

[image]

My environments

- os: `Window 11`
- seaborn: `0.12.2`

Can someone tell me what happened?